# UITableViewCell render differently on 6 and 5c

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

UPDATE: this problem has been fixed, but I don't know the reason why when rendering this view, iPhone 5c + iOS 9 puts contentView at the top of view stacks.

Device 1: iPhone 6 + iOS 10, the tableview cell looks like this, which works all good

[image]

Device 2: iPhone 5c + iOS 9, at the very top, an extra contentView is added, which blocks user interaction with the label and the text field. As you can see below, the highlighted view is the contentView.

[image]

Does anyone have idea about what happens here or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Reveal](https://revealapp.com) might help you work out where it is coming from

Comment: UPDATE: I already solved this, as I send the content view to back, but I just wondering know why this happens? anyone has clues?

Comment: check your autolayouts

Comment: show us the `NSLayoutConstraints` and any code that tampers with your `UI`

Comment: can you please share exact screen shot? it's command+shift+4.